# Promise freezing browser until .then is called

Tags: javascript, promise

```
    this.testfunction = function (file) {

        var bufferPromise = new Response(file).arrayBuffer();
        bufferPromise.then(function (buffer) {
            //do stuff
        });
    };
```

I have a method that needs to retrieve the data from a File object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

arrayBuffer() creates a promise and I use then to execute the rest of my code based on that promise.

Unfortunately until the "then" is fired, my browser freezes up. The method reaches it's end, but I still can't press any other buttons until the promise goes through. Why?

Edit:

```html
    <input id="files" class="hidden" type="file" data-bind="event: { change: function() { testfunction($element.files[0]) } }, click: $element.value=null;">
```

The method is triggered by a knockout binding on an input. The file comes from the input.

Comment: Where/how are you getting `file`?

Comment: Please note that it's **not** "the promise" that's freezing anything. It's the work being done to read the file and fill in the `ArrayBuffer`. Promises are just a means of observing the results of operations, nothing more. (It seems very odd that the `arrayBuffer` method would be doing that...)

Comment: Try using a `FileReader` instead.

Comment: Added how I'm getting the file. I'll have a look at FileReader, but I'm guessing that won't work with uploaded files from input?

Comment: That’s the only thing it’ll work for. What does `Response` add, though? Does it have wider compatibility than `file.arrayBuffer()` directly? (And how big is the file?)

Comment: @Bergi - Or the file's own `arrayBuffer` method, these days. :-)

Comment: @user1539405 - Reading the files identified via `input type="file"` or drag and drop, etc., is specifically what `FileReader` is for. But these days, there's a more modern API for it.

Comment: Ahh, fair. I am, as you can see, not a front end expert. It's a small part of what I'm doing. I'm just trying out a few methods and changes given here now

Comment: What browser are you using? I [just tried](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ht9znqux/) the code above, and it didn't lock up the UI the way you described in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using chrome. I'll have to see if anything else causes it. I'm uploading 10mb files at the moment, the longer it takes to get it into the array is just how long I need to wait. I tried FileReader and the blob without the Response() and both work, but also both freeze, so I imagine it's something else. I'm wondering if the callback from .then using knockout observablearrays may cause it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm slightly surprised using `Response` directly like that works. :-)

Rather than using the `Response` object, you have a couple of options:

1. In modern environments the [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object itself has an [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method it inherits from `Blob` that you can use.
2. In slightly-less modern environments, you can use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)'s [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) method.

Here's an example of #1:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const [file] = this.files;
    if (file) {
        console.log("Reading...");
        file.arrayBuffer()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(`Read ${data.byteLength} bytes`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

That doesn't block the main UI thread while reading the file. (Just checked to be sure.) *(That said, I [tried using `Response`](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/ht9znqux/) and it didn't either...)*

Comment: Thanks, this works fine, but still causes the freeze, so I suppose I have an underlying issue

Comment: @user1539405 - What exactly freezes? It sounds like maybe your application/page just disables buttons and such while reading the file...? Can you do *other* things, like scroll or select text?

Comment: I can still scroll and select text. Is disabling buttons normal in this circumstance then?

Comment: @user1539405 - Okay, so the main UI thread isn't being frozen, it's just that the app is disabling things while the read is happening. Whether that's normal depends entirely on the page/app. If you don't want people to do anything while the file is being loaded, yes. If it's okay that they do other things while the file is loading, no. :-)